# How can I pass optional params to procedure?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, parameters

I have 2 mrthods `save()` and `edit()` entity. When I save entity I check date overlap and if date period unique - save. For that I use oracle procedure. If procedure return >0 rows - this period not unique. When I edit entity - it already in db and I need optional check by id.

```
CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call checkDateRangesOverlap(?,?,?,?)}");
call.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER); // or whatever it is
Date dateStart = Date.from(start.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
Date dateEnd = Date.from(end.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
call.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(dateStart.getTime()));
call.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(dateEnd.getTime()));
call.setLong(4, user.getId());
call.setLong(5, id);
call.execute();
```

but if I create new entity - id is `null` and `call.setLong(5, id);` throw error.

How can I pass optional params to procedure?

Comment: what is the exception ?

Comment: when I save NEW entity id = NULL

Comment: yes can you share the exception please?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: cannot unbox null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your id can be `null`, so instead of using `call.setLong(5, null)` you can use `setNull()` like this :

```
if (id == null) {
    call.setNull(5, java.sql.Types.BIGINT);
} else {
    call.setLong(5, id);
}
```